# Re-write this jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm doing some simple validations using jQuery to check if all textbox are filled. Here the code at the moment:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= btnInsertCountry.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        var codeValue = $("#<%= txtCountryCode.ClientID %>").val();
        var nameValue = $("#<%= txtCountryName.ClientID %>").val();

        if (codeValue == "" || nameValue == "") {
            if (codeValue == "") {
                $("#divCodeValidation").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#divCodeValidation").hide();
            }

            if (nameValue == "") {
                $("#divNameValidation").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#divNameValidation").hide();
            }

            return;
        }
    });
});
```

The divs has the property display to none and contains the error message.
This code works but I don't like it becouse I use an if to check if the values are empty and inside I have a if foreach variable.

Is there a better way to make this validation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as the provided code is working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML5 Features for the common validations
e.g.

```
<form id='form' action='/html5' method='post'>
<input type='text' required>
<input type='email' required>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using standard methods - but mind compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite useful for validation. This jQuery code loops through all the textboxes and check their value. If value is empty then it adds a red color border to let user know that this field is required.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {

   var isValid = true;

   $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {

        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {

            isValid = false;

            $(this).css({

                "border": "1px solid red",

                "background": "#FFCECE"

           });
       }

       else {

            $(this).css({

                "border": "",

                "background": ""

            });
       }

    });

    if (isValid == false) 

       e.preventDefault();

    else
        alert('Thank you for submitting');

});

});
```

Text Box code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:
</td>
<td><input type='text' id='txtFName'/ >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:
</td>
<td><input type='text' id='txtLName'/ >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Age:
</td>
<td><input type='text' id='txtAge'/ >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:
</td>
<td><input type='text' id='txtEmail'/ >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style='text-align:center;'><input type="button"     
id="btnSubmit" value=" Submit ">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code:

```
 body
 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family:Calibri;
  font-size:12pt;
}

td
{
padding:5px;
}
input
{
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:12pt;
}

span
{
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:9pt;
color:red;
}
```